# Syncing videos with python

Tags: python, audio

I am trying to write a program that takes 5 videos and sync them to a song in a loop. But I keep getting this period error.

**When running the code I get this error:**

```
return f(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Mykhaylo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\librosa\beat.py", line 181, in beat_track
beats = __beat_tracker(onset_envelope, bpm, float(sr) / hop_length, tightness, trim)  File "C:\Users\Mykhaylo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\librosa\beat.py", line 579, in __beat_tracker
period = round(60.0 * fft_res / bpm)TypeError: type numpy.ndarray doesn't define __round__ method
```

**Here is the full code**

```
import json
import random
import requests
import librosa
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips

# Fetch multiple random videos from Pexels API
response = requests.get("https://api.pexels.com/videos/search?query=jumping", headers={"Authorization": "563492ad6f91700001000001ffe8bbcab84343649c1acaaad1a446d9"})
response_json = json.loads(response.text)
video_urls = [v['video_files'][0]['link'] for v in response_json['videos']]
random.shuffle(video_urls)

# Load audio file and detect beats
audio, sr = librosa.load('nasty.mp3', sr=None, mono=False)
tempo, beat_frames = librosa.beat.beat_track(y=audio, sr=sr)
beat_times = librosa.frames_to_time(beat_frames, sr=sr)

# Prepare a list to store the subclips
subclips = []

# Process each video
for i, video_url in enumerate(video_urls):
    # Load video file
    video = VideoFileClip(video_url)
    video_duration = video.duration

    # Cut the first 2 seconds of the video
    subclip = video.subclip(0, 2)

    # Loop the subclip as many times as necessary to fit with the audio
    while subclip.duration < beat_times[-1]:
        subclip = concatenate_videoclips([subclip, subclip])

    # Trim the subclip to match the duration of the audio
    subclip = subclip.subclip(0, beat_times[-1])

    subclip = subclip.set_audio(audio)
    subclips.append(subclip)

final_video = concatenate_videoclips(subclips)
final_video.write_videofile("final_video.mp4")
```

Comment: You are giving an array to something that excpets a float it seems, try this: `tempo, beat_frames = librosa.beat.beat_track(y=audio, sr=sr, tempo=float(tempo))`

Comment: have you tried running the full script from a terminal rather than an IDE? your code looks very close to the librosa example for `beat_track`

Comment: @Aaron I have run it from the Terminal too. I get the same error.

Comment: look like issue with library, set `mono=True` and see

Comment: @sahasrara62 `MyVidGen.py", line 31, in <module>
    final_video = concatenate_videoclips(subclips)` this is the error that I got after `mono=True`

Comment: @SeppeWillems where should I define `float(tempo))` cause if I copy paste the code it gets shows as `undefined' and I get an error

Comment: It seems your installed librosa files are corrupted. Try reinstall it.